# Python: using join on a list , output has brackets

Tags: python, list

I feel like its probably a simple solution but I can’t seem to figure it out and my google-fu is failing me.

currently, I’m consuming data from a CSV file, I then read each line and append to a list. I then use join to combine them all but the output is separated by brackets. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
data_file = csv.reader(open(‘data.csv’,’r’))
ip_addr=[]

for row in data_file:
    ip_addr.append(row)

combine_ips = ‘,’.join(map(str, ip_addr))
```

Output

```
[‘1.1.1.1’],[‘1.1.1.2’],[‘1.1.1.3’]
```

What I need: ( I need it to be a string of course)

```
1.1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2,1.1.1.3
```

Comment: How about `ip_addr.append(row[0])`?

Comment: `row` is a list of all the fields in the CSV, so `ip_addr()` is a list of lists.

Comment: Is this really a CSV? It seems like it's just a plain text file with one IP in each line. There are no comma separators.

Comment: of course it does, because the `str` output of a list uses brackets that way. You want to use formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` evaluates as a list even if it is only a list of 1 in your case, so the first thing you need to do is convert `row` to a string before appending it to `ip_addr`.  Then, as pointed out by @wrbp you only need to join the (now) string contents of `ip_addr`:

```
data_file = csv.reader(open("data.csv","r"))
ip_addr=[]

for row in data_file:
    ip_addr.append("".join(row))

combine_ips = ",".join(ip_addr)
```

Comment: :facepalm: , this is it!
That worked. Thanks for the explanation and thanks @wrbp for the hint.